# How to add a user to a user group by default in AWS CDK (Python)?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-userpools

I am creating a AWS Cognito user pool using CDK called `user_pool`. I also created a user group like this:

```
cfn_user_pool_group_default = cognito.CfnUserPoolGroup(
            self, "DefaultGroup",
            user_pool_id=user_pool.user_pool_id,
            description="default group for all commons users",
            group_name="defaultGroup",
        )
```

My goal is to assign every new user to the `user_pool` by the time a user signs up. How can I configure this in AWS CDK?

I searched for something like "set_default_group" for user pools but found nothing.